# Nuxt.JS scss doesn't load svg files

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

Whenever I try to use `background-image: url(~/assets/svg/500.svg)`....
[I get this error](https://hastebin.com/isugitoyiy.coffeescript).
I'm currently using TailwindCSS with PostCss module.

[This is my package.json file](https://hastebin.com/cimowasuxe.json)

[And here's my nuxt.config.js](https://hastebin.com/ohixixodap.js)

I will appreciate any help regarding this issue

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using GULP

`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var base64 = require('gulp-base64-inline');

/**
 * Converts svg and image files to base64
 */

gulp.task('assets', function () {

return gulp.src('assets/scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(base64('/assets/../../'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/styles'));

});
```

usage inside scss, css: `background-image: inline(path/to/image.jpg);`